# Use PageView inside a CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a **`CustomScrollView`** Contain a :-

1- **`SliverToBoxAdapter`** which have tree of widgets

2- **`SliverList`**

The problem is happened when i Wrap **`SliverList`** with **`PageView`**
its normal because **`CustomScrollView`** only accept **`Slivers`**

**code snippet**

```
        CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverToBoxAdapter(child : ),
        PageView(children: <Widget>[SliverList()])]
```

**run result**

A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderRepaintBoundary. RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they coordinate with their children during layout and paint. For example, a RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.

Comment: should the PageView be the child of the SliverToBoxAdapter

   ```    
 CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverToBoxAdapter(child : PageView(children: <Widget>[SliverList()])),
        ]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using `NestedScrollView` :-

`header` property have `SliverToBoxAdapter` it accepts `Slivers`

`body` property have `PageView` it doesn't accept `Slivers`